# VoiceOver: ViewControllers in PageViewControllers are announcing wrong page numbers

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uipageviewcontroller, voiceover

Here is the [demo app](https://github.com/DiaobaoMiaoo/PageViewControllerAccessibilityIssue):

It is a pageViewController with 2 viewControllers.

If you turn voiceOver on and three finger tap on anyway of the viewController, voiceOver will announce page 2 of 3, which is pretty weird cause there have no three pages and no matter which page you are on, it is always page 2.

I guess the expected behaviour is to announce the correct page number or don't read the page number at all.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found this in documentation anywhere, but my best guess is that the UIPageViewControllerDataSource defines two required methods:

pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:
pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:

Therefore, the UIPageViewController is only ever aware of three view controllers, of which you are only ever seeing number 2 of 3. Might just be default behavior based on Apple's implementation.